# Обучение JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Хочу по советоваться. Как научиться JavaScript, то есть может есть какие либо ресурсы, книги. Я бы не стал сюда писать, но даже если просто погуглить или забить в ютубе выдает ролики которым по 3 и более лет. Извиняюсь что может написал не в тему и засоряю форум.

Comment: Я уверен, что даже книги с трехгодичной давностью будут полезны для изучения JavaScript. После этого вы можете познакомиться со спецификацией последнего релиза языка.

Comment: метанит или learn.javascript

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить несколько вариантов, может найдете для себя что-то полезное:

1. [Степик](https://stepik.org/course/2223/promo)
2. [SoloLearn](https://www.sololearn.com/Course/JavaScript/)
3. Моррисон М. — Изучаем JavaScript (O'Reilly) - хоть и старая книга, зато все доступно описано.